# what is .travis.yml file in python flask openshift application?

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I'm new using python on openshift and I follow this tutorial to learn more about it https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html, then there is a thing that I can't find info in openshift docs or https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html

I suspect is defining the execution order of https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-repository-layout.html

Am I right or I missing something else?

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/

Comment: It is something like jenkins?

Comment: Yes, "exactly" like jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to automatically deploy your application.
See [this link](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/openshift/).
Check also this [link](https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/travis-ci-on-openshift)